# How long should I wait before choosing a hash function?

Tags: hash, secure-coding

How long should I wait before using a newer (hopefully improved) hash function? For instance:

Is SHA-3 ready for use because of extra testing that went on during the NIST competition?

Comment: sha-3 is ready for use now. imho it's better for hashing; more of the qualities we want for a hash.

Comment: you mean, "when is a hash function deemed ready?" ? Or, "how long should I wait before replacing existing hash functions with newer ones?" ? Your title is ... ambiguous

Comment: What are you using the hash function for? Password storage? Something else?

Comment: @Anders, See my comments on the accepted answer.  I'm looking for a general-purpose hash function that has longevity (unlike SHA-1). SHA-3 fits the bill, **as long as it is wrapped in PBKDF2 when used for passwords**.

Comment: @schroeder, I was under the impression that new hash functions (or crypto in general) shouldn't be used until it has been in the wild for awhile, but perhaps that was mistaken.

Comment: @NH. I'm asking you what *you* mean

Comment: @NH. _"new crypto shouldn't be used until it has been in the wild for a while"_. Yes, I agree. NIST also agrees. That's why they have **very long** competitions (aka "public scrutiny periods") before writing up a standard for something. In particular, the SHA-3 competition ran from initial submissions in Oct 2008, to final winner in Oct 2012, with NSA and university profs hammering away at the submissions for those 4 years. That should certainly count as "in the wild for a while".

Comment: However, your skepticism is valid for non-NIST-approved crypto like twofish or argon2 which have not necessarily had the same level of public scrutiny that a NIST competition brings.

Comment: So, @MikeOunsworth, you think the [Password Hashing Competition](https://password-hashing.net/) did not do as well as the NIST competition?

Comment: @NH. "Amount of public scrutiny" is a hard thing to measure, but yes, my claim is that anything backed by NIST / NSA will naturally get more research budget thrown at trying to break it (esp from the classified intelligence community) because the American government will then use it to protect their national secrets. The argon2 comp, by comparison, only ran for 2 years, and probably didn't attract the same amount of research budget from big organizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How long should I wait before using a newer (hopefully improved) hash function?

The better question to ask is: "*How long should I wait before switching off my current hash*". What are you on now? If your data is protected with MD5 or SHA1 then please switch. Please switch now. If you're already on something that's believed to be unbroken, then you have no reason to "upgrade".

The general rule with crypto is to assume everything will be broken eventually, so pick something that's not known to be broken at the time, and have a plan in place to switch your data over to a new algorithm in a hurry if an attack does get published.

At the time of writing, the following are all perfectly acceptable, not known to be broken, [hash functions / key derivation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Unkeyed_cryptographic_hash_functions):

- BLAKE, SHA2, SHA3, ... , bcrypt, scrypt, PBKDF2, argon2, ...

Choose the one that best fits your application.

---

> Is SHA-3 ready for use because of extra testing that went on during the NIST competition?

If NIST has standardized it (which they have in [FIPS-202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf)), then it's ready for use!

As @RoryAlsop said, beware that if you need your data to be compatible with multiple pieces of software, then be aware of compatibility issues; just because SHA3's been standardized for two years, doesn't mean that it's been widely adopted.

---

One final note, reading between the lines, you seem to be implying that SHA3 is a "a newer (hopefully improved) hash function". I want to correct this.

While it is newer, it is not "better" than SHA2, in fact SHA3 offers exactly the same security levels as SHA2. NIST launched the SHA3 competition not because they wanted to "improve" on SHA2, but because they were uncomfortable with the "all your eggs in one basket" nature of only having one approved hash algorithm. That's not to say there's anything wrong with SHA2, but if something does come up, they want to have a migration path at the ready.

---

### SHA3 for password hashing.

Bad idea. SHA3 is ideal for file hashing (because it's fast), but it would actually be considered a weakness to use it for password hashing (because it's fast).

See [NIST SP-800-63b](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html):

> Examples of suitable key derivation functions include Password-based Key Derivation Function 2 (PBKDF2) [SP 800-132] and Balloon [BALLOON]. A memory-hard function SHOULD be used because it increases the cost of an attack.

SHA3 is designed to be efficient, it is neither slow (time-hard) nor big (memory-hard).

[PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) and [Balloon](https://crypto.stanford.edu/balloon/) are schemes that wrap around a standard hash function to make it time-hard / memory-hard, respectively. So if you only wanted to support one hashing primitive in, say, your embedded hardware device, you can wrap PBKDF2 / Balloon around SHA3 and still have FIPS-certified crypto, but please don't use naked SHA3 on passwords.

Comment: I thought SHA3 offered customizability of computation time (think baloon or scrypt or something that can have lots of iterations to slow it down). Is that true?

Comment: @NH. uhh, not sure. I thought `rate` and `capacity` (the block size and internal state size) where the only tunable params. My understanding is that a requirement of the SHA3 competition was "efficient in software and hardware", and hardware likes fixed constants. You can certainly wrap SHA3 inside a construction like repeated-salt-and-hash, or PBKDF2 to get tunable computation time. But if you want a slow hash function, then something designed to be efficient probably isn't for you; go with scrypt or argon2 which are explicitely designed to be inefficient.

Comment: oh how sad.  I really wanted a one-hash-function-to-rule-them-all!  Guess I'll still have to use (& recommend) a different function for file hashing than for password hashing.

Comment: @NH. lol yeah. SHA3 is ideal for file hashing (because it's fast), but it would actually be considered a weakness to use it for password hashing (because it's fast). I'll edit something into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, once a function has been approved as a replacement for an existing one it is worth looking at how you would migrate, so that once there are identified weaknesses you can carry out that transition.

New functions are developed so that there is a replacement - as it is a given that weaknesses will be found in older ones.

So it's not a case of waiting for the new function to have extra testing (although obviously for approval by e.g. NIST there is a lot of testing that has happened)  - its a case of waiting for there to be a need.